# How can I find remotely the NVIDIA graphics drivers version on Windows XP clients?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, remote

How can I find remotely the NVIDIA graphics drivers version installed on a set of Windows XP clients?

Answer (score 2):

There's a registry key you can query to find out the version. Check the version value under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer
```

It will be in the format of 8.16.1**1.9107** where the last bit (bolded) is the interesting part. Convert that to 191.07 and you have you driver version number.

I'll leave it up to you to write the script to retrieve this from all machines since that's not something I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `REG` command (it's included in XP) to access the registry from the command line and `psexec` (a part of the [**PsTools**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) at Sysinternals) to execute this command remotely on the computers you want.

Assuming the key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer** listed by Pär Björklund is correct (I can't check, I'm an ATI guy ;-) ), that would be:

```
psexec \\servername -u username -p password reg query "HKEY\LOCAL\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Installer"
```

With the `@filename` syntax instead of the `\\servername` in psexec, you can even run the command on a list of computers.

And add a `/v "ValueName"` as the end of the command (it's a parameter for `reg`) to get only the content of one value, not the content of the whole key.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to find the driver's version needs remote desktop:

Right-click on the desktop, choose NVIDIA Control Panel, then on the menu Help / System Information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Remote System Information](http://remote-system-information.en.softonic.com/).

[image]

This shareware allows you to get system information on computers from a domain, or direct name or ip. It also contains information on driver versions, as well as on other programs.

I tried only shortly on my own computer, I don't know how it works with permissions over the network.

It seems to require that guest account is activated on remote computers, from what I understand of their readme.